# Checking to see if signal arrived for given resolution

Tags: c, unix

I have a server and client codes that IPC with each other via named pipes(FIFO). Client sends SIGNAL(SIGUSR1 for example) to Server and checking to see if any signal arrived with given time resolution(via command line argument). Server checks (if its 5ms) 5ms everytime, checks if any signal arrived after 5ms , if arrived it does some code , if not continues until it catches a signal.

So here is that what my problem lies. I dont know what to use for these kind of action. I looked up "Unix Systems Programming: Communication, Concurrency, and Threads  Kay A. Robbins , Steven Robbins" found some functions that might be use for me. Sleep,Alarm,uSleep,NanoSleep,Pause. But i dont know which one to use in my situation. Sleep is out of question i think due it takes seconds and i think it overflows when you try to convert to milliseconds.

A little code snippet or psudocode would be nice to understand for me.

I simply asking how to check if signal arrived in given resolution frequency. I have to check if signal arrived in those milliseconds. Check any given "n" mseconds if signal catched.

Comment: This is unclear - presumably you've registered a signal handler, but beyond that I can't tell what you're describing.

Comment: I did a signal handler yes. I have 2 programs one is called Timeserver other is client. Timeserver gets clicks in milliseconds to check if signal arrived in that given argument. like "./timeserver 5" would check for signal in every 5  milliseconds. If there is signal , signal handler would run of course. I basically want to block and unblock for given "milliseconds argument"

Comment: You don't want to block and unblock. You want the signal handler to set a flag if a signal arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the function nanosleep (and also usleep) could work!

1. You have to install a signal handler for the desired signal      that can be catched by the program, e.g.:

   ```
   #include <signal.h>
   /* Handler for the signals */
   void my_handler(int signum)
   {
       if(signum == SIGUSR1) {
       /* Perform an action on signal SIGUSR1*/
       }
   }
   int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
       /* .... */
       /* Install the signal handler to catch the desired signals*/
       signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);
       /* .... */
   }
   ```
2. You have to loop and wait for a signal. And if you catch a signal you have to perform the actions either inside the handler or using the exception that raise when nanosleep is interrupted.

   ```
    #include <time.h> /* Contains nanosleep + timespec definition */
    #include <errno.h> /* Contains the errno variable and the ERROR_CODE macros */
    #include <stdio.h> /* Contains definition of perror */
    #include <stdlib.h> /* Contains the exit function */

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
      /* fetch milliseconds from argv and put in a variable named "ms" */
      struct timespec interval;
      interval.tv_sec = 0; /* Seconds*/ 
      interval.tv_nsec = ms*1e6; /* 10^6 Nanoseconds = 1 millisecond */
      struct timespec interrupted;
      /* .. */
      while(1) {
          if(nanosleep(&interval, &interrupted) != 0){
              /* The sleeping was interrupted! */
              if(errno == EINTR){
                   //The interruption is due to a signal
              }
              else {
                   /*The interruption is due to another cause (read the man page) --> Print an error message */
                   perror("Nanosleep"); 
                   break; /* Exit from main loop */
              }
       } 
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
   ```

Alternatively you can also deal the signals inside the handlers.

**Alternative Solution**
If you are sure that a signal will ever come and don't need to control each 5 milliseconds you could also use the function `pause`. In fact the man page says:

> pause causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal
>          is delivered that either terminates the process or causes  the
>          invocation of a signal-catching function.

In this case you have only to install the signal handler and wait.

Let me know if it answered your question.

Sincerly yours,
Mirko

Comment: Thank you while loop solution works for me. Even though i know it will %100 give me signal i have to use the stupid way cause thats how they wanted to design.kudos